# How to extend a vagrant plugin through Vagrantfile without changing the .rb file?

Tags: ansible, vagrant, vagrant-plugin, rhel8

I have this scenario in Vagrant where I wanted to patch how the ansible is being installed on RHEL 8 (because of certain issues with absence of packages missing due to repository setup) using ansible_local plugin. So here's the thing. Instead, I wanted to use pip3 (though I know I can use pip using ansible_local module but still it errs after that due to absence of certain repository so I figure out a way to fix it).

In my Vagrantfile, I have these lines as such,

```ruby
.....
      node.vm.provision "ansible_local" do |ansible|
        ansible.playbook = ansible_playbook
        ansible.verbose = true
        ansible.install = true
        ## Actually this line doesn't suffice my problem since it still errs as pip requires other packages. Please check the *.rb file below
        if i == 100
            ansible.install_mode = "pip"
            ansible.version = "2.9"
            #ansible.ansible_rpm_install = Foo
        end
      end
...
.....
```

But because using pip still fails, so I end up changing the file `/opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.9/gems/vagrant-2.2.9/plugins/provisioners/ansible/cap/guest/redhat/ansible_install.rb` and what I did is this way,

```ruby
cap/guest/redhat/ansible_install.rb
require_relative "../facts"
require_relative "../pip/pip"

module VagrantPlugins
  module Ansible
    module Cap
      module Guest
        module RedHat
          module AnsibleInstall

            def self.ansible_install(machine, install_mode, ansible_version, pip_args, pip_install_cmd = "")
              case install_mode
              when :pip
                pip_setup machine, pip_install_cmd
                Pip::pip_install machine, "ansible", ansible_version, pip_args, true
              when :pip_args_only
                pip_setup machine, pip_install_cmd
                Pip::pip_install machine, "", "", pip_args, false
              else
                
                // My added part as a quick fix/solution
                if machine.config.vm.box == "generic/rhel8"
                   ansible_rpm_install_rhel8 machine
                elsif
                   ansible_rpm_install machine
                end
                
              end
            end

            private

            def self.ansible_rpm_install(machine)
              rpm_package_manager = Facts::rpm_package_manager(machine)

              epel = machine.communicate.execute "#{rpm_package_manager} repolist epel | grep -q epel", error_check: false
              if epel != 0
                machine.communicate.sudo 'sudo rpm -i https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-`rpm -E %dist | sed -n \'s/.*el\([0-9]\).*/\1/p\'`.noarch.rpm'
              end
              machine.communicate.sudo "#{rpm_package_manager} -y --enablerepo=epel install ansible"
            end

            def self.pip_setup(machine, pip_install_cmd = "")
              rpm_package_manager = Facts::rpm_package_manager(machine)

              machine.communicate.sudo("#{rpm_package_manager} -y install curl gcc libffi-devel openssl-devel python-crypto python-devel python-setuptools")
              Pip::get_pip machine, pip_install_cmd
            end

            def self.pip_setup(machine, pip_install_cmd = "")
              rpm_package_manager = Facts::rpm_package_manager(machine)

              machine.communicate.sudo("#{rpm_package_manager} -y install curl gcc libffi-devel openssl-devel python-crypto python-devel python-setuptools")
              Pip::get_pip machine, pip_install_cmd
            end

            
            // My added part as a quick fix/solution
            def self.ansible_rpm_install_rhel8(machine)
              rpm_package_manager = Facts::rpm_package_manager(machine)

              epel = machine.communicate.execute "#{rpm_package_manager} repolist epel | grep -q epel", error_check: false
              if epel != 0
                machine.communicate.sudo 'sudo rpm -i https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-`rpm -E %dist | sed -n \'s/.*el\([0-9]\).*/\1/p\'`.noarch.rpm'
              end
              machine.communicate.sudo "dnf -y update; dnf -y install python3 python3-pip; pip3 install ansible"
            end
            
            
          end
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

So I added a method  `self.ansible_rpm_install_rhel8(machine)` and did an `if..elsif` as a solution when box name is `"generic/rhel8"`. This works perfect actually on my end. However, I don't like this approach i.e. changing the file `/opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.9/gems/vagrant-2.2.9/plugins/provisioners/ansible/cap/guest/redhat/ansible_install.rb` because once it changes or version upgrades, this will be gone. Is there any better way that I can just do this only inside Vagrantfile such that perhaps overriding or extending the class itself? I have no idea how to do this.

Any ideas are welcome.

Thank you!

Comment: You can use more than one provisioning. Have you tried `shell` provisioning before execution the ansible one? In that, you can pre-config (add, update...) the repositories and add some packages as you wish.

Comment: Hi @Mark, thanks for adding that. Ahm, can you set an example on how to do this? I might be able to grasp you though it's not clear what exactly you have in mind there...Thanks btw for your inputs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use multiple provisioning sections next one another which will be executed in the order as you defined them in your `Vagrantfile`.

Instead of patching a plugin, try to prepare your ansible execution accordingly.

Before executing the provisioning part for ansible, execute a **shell provisioning** as follows:

```rb
Vagrant.configure("2") do |node|

    # ...

    node.vm.provision :shell, path: "fix_repo_and_add_packages.sh"

    node.vm.provision "ansible_local" do |ansible|
        ansible.playbook = ansible_playbook
        ansible.verbose = true
        ansible.install = true
        ## Actually this line doesn't suffice my problem since it still errs as pip requires other packages. Please check the *.rb file below
        if i == 100
            ansible.install_mode = "pip"
            ansible.version = "2.9"
            #ansible.ansible_rpm_install = Foo
        end
    end

end
```

Your `fix_repo_and_add_packages.sh` contains the setup of the missing repos and here you can add packages as well.

For more information about shell provisioning, you can find in the [doc](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/provisioning/shell)

Comment: Thanks @Mark. It actually works that way. For some users who wanted to fix or override issues, just make sure you are enclosing if/else conditions in such a way if you have multiple nodes and/or various OS to support but have issues with other OS versions.